# How to write a for loop for a column with texts in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk import tokenize


df = pd.DataFrame(['I would like to divide each paragraph into sentences. I am asking on SO because there are very good people who know Python better than me. I am confident they will sort it out.', 'Hello guys. It was a nice day. Yet, now I need to sort this issue.', 'I have used R and MATLAB so far. MATLAB remains my favourite. We will see with Python how it goes.', 'Ciao. I would like to solve this. Can you help me?'], columns = ['Text'])
```

What I want to do is to apply `sent_tokenize()` to every element in the column "Text". So far I tried this and some variations:

```
sentences = []

for i in range(0,len(df)-1):
 sentences = tokenize.sent_tokenize(df.iloc[i])
```

I keep failing. Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for t in df['Text'].values:
    sentences = tokenize.sent_tokenize(t)
```

or if you just want a list:

```
[tokenize.sent_tokenize(t) for t in df['Text'].values]
```

or use `iterrows()`:

```
[tokenize.sent_tokenize(t['Text']) for _, t in df.iterrows()]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll mark it as the correct answer once SO will allow me to do so

Comment: @Z Li Any idea why in my real dataframe when I use your codes it tells me: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`?

Comment: can you `print(t)` or add some sample code to make sure the content of the dataframe are actually strings? This error seems to come from `sent_tokenize` and it is complaining it is not receiving strings.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with it. It prints text but it is not clearly string otherwise it would work. Any tips to turn my text into string?

Comment: can you try `print(type(t))` for each t in `df['Text']`? I feel they are some class represented as a str. I need more clues to try to give a suggestion.

Comment: They are all `str`. Sorry if I can't provide you with more clues, it's a kind of mystery what I see in my df :D thanks for your help :)